# CsvReader Next function

Tags: python, csv

i am given a csv file but i want to skip the first row of data and move on to the next. Here is my code:

```
def read_csv(inputfile):
    return list(csv.reader(inputfile)) #<-----

def generate_xml(reader,outfile):
    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)        
    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    description = SubElement(head,'description')
    current_group = None
    i = 1
    for row in reader.next(): #<-----
        x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
        if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
            current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

            collar = SubElement(current_group,'collar')
            toe = SubElement(current_group,'toe')
            cost1 = SubElement(current_group,'cost')
            collar.text = ','.join((x1,y1,z1))
            toe.text = ','.join((x2,y2,z2))
            cost1.text = cost
        i+=1
    head.set('total_holes', '%s'%i)
    indent.indent(root)
    tree.write(outfile)
```

As you can see, i return the csv file as a list then i pass it onto the generate_xml function. However when i run the complete program there is an

```
error: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have a *list*, not an iterator. Just slice it instead:

```
for row in reader[1:]:
```

or skip that first row when you still have an actual `csv.reader()` object:

```
def read_csv(inputfile):
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    next(reader)
    return list(reader)
```

You'd be better off returning the `reader` object instead of reading all rows into memory there; unless you absolutely need random access to the rows.

You also should really use the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) instead as it works for Python 2.6+ and 3, where the iterator `.next()` method has been renamed to `.__next__()`.

You'd otherwise *never* use `for row in reader.next()`, because `.next()` on a `csv.reader()` iterator returns *one* row.

Answer (score 6):

For python 2.x, the code is:

```
data = []
with open('xxx.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    name = r.next()[1] # assume the first 2 rows are name and unit
    unit = r.next()
    for row in r:
        data.append(row)
```

For python 3.x, use `next(r)` instead of `r.next()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np

path = "file.csv"
data = np.loadtxt(path, dtype=np.float32, delimiter=",",skiprows=1)
```